# Software // System/library/frameworks -> deleted QTKIT.framework

Tags: finder

Deleted by accident -> QTKIT.framework folder. Finder crashes on start-up as do most applications.

Any idea how I can restore this? No time-machine back up.

Yosemite 10.10.5
macbook pro 2011

Comment: @Mark QT stands for QuickTime here :-)

Answer (score 3):

Boot to [Recovery HD and select reinstall OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314).

That will reinstall the current OS and repopulate the frameworks that are missing. This isn't designed to erase your Mac, but you are flying without a safety harness with no backup.